# How to say "the fourth floor of that building"?

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin

My doubt is in translating this sentence:

*"That apartment is in the fourth floor of that building*."

Is there a grammatical structure to say things like "the fourth floor of that building" in Chinese?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

> the fourth floor of that building

It can be written in traditional Chinese 那棟建築物的(of that building)四樓(the fourth floor). Add 那棟建築物的 before 四樓 can describe that the 四樓 you said is from that building.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- 那座建筑物的四楼 (measure word: 座)
- 那栋建筑物的四楼 (measure word: 栋)

Note: both measure words are appropriate for buildings.

Comment: In my classes I've been working with the word 层 for floor. Is: 那座建筑物的四层 valid?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "the fourth floor of that building" in Chinese, be sure to put "the building" in the front and "the fourth floor" in the back.

The order of expression of building number and floor is opposite to English.

In standard Chinese, this sentence is used to mean: "那套公寓位于那栋楼的四层。"

Answer (score 0):

办公室在那栋楼的四楼。
The office is on the fourth floor of that building.

Answer (score 0):

Both 四楼 and 四层 can work. If you must be emphatically specific, say 那楼房的第四层